# useStyles is not dynamically assigning properties based on variable change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Based on a boolean state change, I'm trying to change the style of a component, but for some reason, it's only displaying the change after a page refresh.

In my parent App component, I do the following:

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "./Layout";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(!loading);
    }, 2000);
  }, [loading]);
  return <Layout loading={loading} />;
}
```

And my `Layout` component catches this `loading` variable and send it to the `makeStyles` hook,

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  wrapper: ({ loading }) => ({
    paddingTop: 64,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("lg")]: {
      paddingLeft: loading ? 0 : 100
    }
  })
}));

const Layout = React.memo(({ loading }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ loading });

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div>side</div>
      <div className={classes.wrapper}>
        is loading: {JSON.stringify(loading)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});

export default Layout;
```

Doing a `console.log` after `wrapper: ({ loading }) => ({` prints the correct value of `loading`, but the style is not changing.

What's going on here?

[image: eloquent-proskuriakova-jsc5s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is two issues in your code , the first one is that you use object destructuring two times :
instead of

`const Layout = React.memo(({ loading }) => { const classes = useStyles({ loading });`

you should :

`const Layout = React.memo(({ loading }) => { const classes = useStyles(loading );`

because in your first level you have access to the property loading, second issue is that you're invoking the parameter in the wrong place, you must invoke the loading directly in the css property, like this :

```
paddingLeft: (loading) => (loading ? 0 : 100)
```

here is a link with the two corrections ,hope that what you are expecting
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-microservice-y2gql?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark